# How to avoid duplication between templates in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, view

Suppose all the views in my site should include some shared content, for example a navbar at the top. How can this be acheived, without duplicating the navbar markup across all the views?

I'm looking for the most standard way to do this in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your index page have a navbar, and footer, then have an ng-view div.

You'll need to include the ngRoute module, and the script tag linking to it.

You'll have a div like this.

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

You'll have a partialRoutes.js file looking something like this.

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: './partials/things.html'
    })
    .when('/stuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/stuff.html'
    })
    .when('/otherstuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/otherstuff.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
    })
});
```

When you include ngRoute it will look something like this.

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
Here are the docs for ngRoute. Hope I helped.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router
"It provides a different approach than ngRoute in that it changes your application views based on state of the application and not just the route URL."